# Statics Files Django on Heroku Deployment

Tags: django, heroku, static

I have my app runnning in Heroku, everything works really good with my models and forms, but there is a problem, I can't see any of my styles neither for my templates not for Django Grappelli, how can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Check the path that your images/styles are trying to reference. Ensure that your `STATIC_URL` is a relative path. Also ensure that your `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` are not the same.
Ex:

#### settings/base.py

```
from unipath import Path

# Project directory root assuming: yourapp.settings.base
PROJECT_DIR = Path(__file__).ancestor(3)

# Static files
STATIC_ROOT = PROJECT_DIR.child("static")

# URL prefix for static files.
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

This layout follows the directory structure similar to:

```
project_name/
|-- app 1
    |-- models.py
    |-- views.py
    ...

|-- project_name
    |-- settings
        |-- base.py
        |-- local.py
        |-- dev.py
        ...
```

Also by default Heroku should collectstatic when you upload your project however if you have modified this setting ensure to call:

`python manage.py collectstatic`

you can then check to see if static files are present in the specified folder (in the example above it would be in `/static/`