# Django static img not showing in my blog

Tags: python, django, image, templates, static

first of all let me say that im a student trying to learn django...
i finished my app throught a tutorial and im having a problem with an image showing in my template, its just showing the frame with out the image... here is my html code:

```
            <aside>
                <h4>Historico</h4>
                {% for month in months %}
                <p><a href="{url 'blog.views.month' month.0 month.1}">{{ month.2 }}</a></p>

                {% endfor %}
                <h4>Sobre mi</h4>
                <img class="pic" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/static/img/foto.jpg"  alt="foto"/>

                <img class="picbig" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/static/img/foto.jpg"  alt="foto grande"/>
                <p>Soy un doge san OP platino IV lan pls</p>
            </aside>
```

my image "foto.jpg" isnt showing, here is my settings.py for static

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
"C:/Users/Abdul Hamid/PycharmProjects/misitioweb/static",
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',

)
```

and my img is in a folder like this

```
`C:\Users\User-Name\PycharmProjects\misitioweb\`

`blog-
-templtates
--frontpage.html
--otherthing.html
-__init__.py
-admin.py
-models.py
-test.py
-views.py
mysite-
-__init__.py
-settings.py
-urls.py
-wsgi.py
manage.py
-etc..
static-
--img
---foto.jpg
`
```

i have been trying to change the code in the img tag for diferent ressults like loading the static folder into the template like this:
`{{from static import staticfiles}}`

im doing something wrong, i already tryied searching for more info but nothing have worked... please help me!
anyway
thanks for your time

Comment: You should go through the official django tutorial.  It's quite good, not long, and easy to understand.  Im not going to tell you where, but you'll find the answer in here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your src attribute is incorrect for you image.

```
<img class="pic" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/static/img/foto.jpg"  alt="foto"/>
```

should be

```
<img class="pic" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/foto.jpg"  alt="foto"/>
```

Since STATIC_URL is already taking care of adding /static/ to your url. If you use the debugger tools in your browser and take a look at the src for that image you'll probably see it saying "/static/static/img/foto.jpg" when it should be "/static/img/foto.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

Also ensure you have collected the static image files by running:

```
python manange.py collectstatic
```

Comment: ImproperlyConfigured("You're using the staticfiles app "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.

Comment: should i move something in my static_root on my settings.py?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252056/statics-files-django-on-heroku-deployment/23254817#23254817